# verilog modeling output x

Tags: verilog

Lets consider the following code, I want to make the b x for #2 whenever a changes

```
module test();
reg [3:0] a;
initial 
begin
    $vcdpluson();
    a <=0;
    #5
    a <= 1;
    #5
    a <= 2;
    #1
    a <= 3;
    #4
    a <= 5;
end
reg [3:0] b;
always @(a)
begin
    b = 3'bx;
    b = #2 a;
end
endmodule
```

I am getting the following waveform from simulation

[image]

When a changes from 1->2 and 2->3, I expect the always block to get triggered(since the sensitivity list has only a). after #2 from 2->3 transition b should have become 3. But looks like after #1 b has become 3, it means the always @(a) loop didn't get triggered for the 2->3 transition of a. How to enable that ?

Comment: You have to post complete waveform with signal names, not a part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you are using blocking assignments to write to `b`. That means your `always @a` procedure gets *blocked* for 2 time units before its able to see the next change on `a`.

By using a non-blocking assignment, the assignment gets queued, and the always procedure immediately goes back to the top waiting for the next change on `a`

```
always @(*)
begin
    b <= 3'bx;
    b <= #2 a;
end
```

Comment: even if you use non blocking statement it wont work

Comment: What's the meaning of 'won't work'? ,  are the waveforms exactly the same? You haven't edited your question to include more details on waveforms after and before changes made to the code.@arun